# Laravel mix - 404 error on routes with two levels

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I have a small issue with my current configuration using Laravel for the backend, and Vue in the frontend, while my application is built using Laravel mix (6.0).

I am using the following simple mix configuration:

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js/app.js")
    .vue()
    .version()
    .extract();
```

Everything works fine when running `npm run watch`, and when I launch the production build, I get as expected three files in my public folder (manifest.js, app.js and vendor.js). I included these three files in my app.blade.php file in the following way:

```
<script src="{{ asset(mix('js/manifest.js')) }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset(mix('js/vendor.js')) }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset(mix('js/app.js')) }}" defer></script>
```

The mix-manifest.json that comes out looks like this:

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js?id=55e00bb7adfe7cc8d33c",
    "/js/vendor.js": "/js/vendor.js?id=3cc2a9d83cabdff07b38",
    "/js/manifest.js": "/js/manifest.js?id=7d6950016e73d672d079",
}
```

Most of the routes are working just fine with such a configuration.

However, the problem I am facing is a generic 404 error that shows up when trying to access particular routes having at least two levels, such as <my_website>/read/<post_id>. In this case, the browser tries to resolve something like <my_website>/read/js/app/1.js which obviously doesn't exist, as it should search for <my_website>/js/app/1.js instead.

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there any way to include a full path in the manifest file to avoid this, and making sure that the browser resolves the correct files? Or any other work around to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: The browser surely will not use your app's routes to find a file. Have you tried using a [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag?

Comment: Okay great, I've posted it again as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a base URL in the browser. This rewrites the URLs for you.

**Use the `<base>` tag**

See documentation of the base tag here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Example:

```html
<base href="https://www.example.com/">
```